# Prove or disprive that $n^{2}-n+17$ is prime for all integers $n$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, prime-numbers

I am looking to prove this function is always prime for all integers $n$: $$n^{2}-n+17$$
I have tested it for the first $10$ integers and it seems to work but I am not sure how to prove it form all $n$. Any ideas?

Comment: Well it doesnt work. Try 17.

Comment: No polynomial function can work.

Comment: Well spotted - of course I had to stop at 10! Thanks for that!

Comment: See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Prime-GeneratingPolynomial.html and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formula_for_primes

Comment: In general, try to prove the conjecture by induction....

Comment: Of course, $n^2-n+41$ is much nicer ...

Comment: ... because $e^{\sqrt{4\cdot41-1}\pi}$ is much closer to an integer than  $e^{\sqrt{4\cdot17-1}\pi}$

Comment: And there are some more with a number less than 17

Comment: ... that is, all the numbers starting with $1^2-1+p$ and stopping at $p^2-p+p$ are prime.

Comment: Testing a Diophantine relation on 10 values is certainly not enough. It is not exceptional that you need to try a billion values or so before you find a counterexample !

Answer (score 7):

$n^2-n+17=n(n-1)+17$. Taking $n=17$, you will get $17\times16+17$, a proper multiple of $17$. Taking $n-1=17$, you will get $18\times17+17$, another one.

More generally, a polynomial expression $P(n)$ with integer coefficients will fail for $n=P(0)$ and multiples.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(x)=a_0+a_1x+...+a_nx^n \in \mathbb Z[X]$ be a polynomial. Now note that

$$f(a_0)=a_0+a_1a_0+...+a_na_0^n=a_0(1+a_1+...+a_na_0^{n-1})$$

In other words, $a_0$ divides $f(a_0)$. Therefore, if $1<a_0<f(a_0)$ like in your case, $f(a_0)$ is not prime.

Comment: You need to say a little more.  In particular, the second factor could be $0$ or $\pm 1$.  However, since $a_0|f(ka_0)$, and since a polynomial of degree $n$ can only take a particular value at most $n$ times, we just need to try $3(n-1)+1$ different values of $k$ to find a value where the second factor is nontrivial.

Answer (score 0):

The formula $\quad n^2-n+C\quad $ is composite for many values where $n>C$ and always composite for $n=C^p, p\in\mathbb{N}.$